# Consulta MySQL desde script

Tags: mysql, shell, script

Tengo un ordenador conectado por SSH a otro equipo desde el cual quiero ejecutar un script bash que haga una consulta a un host externo en MySQL.

Yo me conecto sin problema desde linea de comandos como sigue:

```
mysql -h HOST -u USER -pPASS
```

Una vez conectado utilizo la base de datos y demás sin problema.

El problema viene al utilizar esa misma línea en mi script, se me queda bloqueado el script en ese punto un tiempo y posteriormente me envía un mensaje de error como el que sigue:

> ```
> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'HOST' (110)
> ```

Este es mi código:

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
        echo "Usage method: script-file + nodes-file"
        exit 0
fi

NODES=$1
HOST="host"
USER="usuario"
PASS="Contraseña"
DB="BASE"
DATENOW=`date +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M --date "+2 hours"`
mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p$PASS -D $DB -e "SHOW TABLES;"
```

Comment: prueba primero a hacer un ping en ese servidor al HOST que tiene el mysql, no vaya a ser que no tengas resolución dns en el servidor y te este dando problemas eso. Es decir, entra con ssh a ese equipo, y ejecuta **ping HOST**, a ver si puede resolverlo

Comment: Buenas Jakala, he hecho lo que me has comentado y el HOST no me devuelve el ping.

Comment: Alvaro: entonces, ¿ejecutas el script desde el mismo ordenador donde corre el MySQL?

Comment: No, el script se ejecuta desde el equipo 'X' y se intenta conecta al equipo 'Y'. No se si me explico.

Comment: Sí, entiendo. ¿No será que no pasas correctamente los parámetros? Si tienen caracteres raros o espacios debes utilizar comillas: `mysql -h "$HOST"...` [[Por cierto, usa `@` (como @fedorqui) para responder a la gente. Así recibiremos notificaciones cuando lo hagas]]

Comment: @fedorqui Mmmm no creo que sea ese el problema aunque no estoy seguro asi que te comento, el HOST es una IP, el usuario si que puede dar problemas ya que tiene dos guiones bajos '_' al igual que la base de datos (esta solo tiene un guion bajo), respecto a la contraseña no creo que sea problema son letras y números.

Comment: Dado que el error solamente te da desde el script, el error al pasar los parámetros parece el más lógico. Yo probaría escribiendo un `echo` para ver qué se está pasando exactamente. Es decir, pondría `echo mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p$PASS -D $DB -e "SHOW TABLES;"`; luego ejecutaría lo que te salga para  intentar replicar el error.

Comment: Vale, solucionado el problema es que no puse cuidado al poner la IP del HOST y se me coló un número que no era. Muchas gracias a todos y un saludo!!! @fedorqui